# How to fix listview value single string have multiple value for android

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

```
String sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("numbers");
final String[] values = new String[]{sessionId};
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values));
final ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "listValue -" + values[i]);
    arrayList.add(values[i]);
}

listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
listView.setAdapter(new 

ArrayAdapter(ListDisplayActivity.this,R.layout.list_display,R.id.text, arrayList));
```

How to fix listview value single string have multiple values for android?

Comment: Please ask it a little bit clearer.

Comment: are you trying to pass a List to another activity?

Comment: The sessionid have multiple value.. when I try to view in listview the value are individual display.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values like

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("sessionIds",yourSessionIdList);
```

and get like

```
ArrayList<String> sessionIds = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("sessionIds");
```

Check the below link: You may need to use custom adapter to display multiple values in each row of listview:

[Listview with custom adapter](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/custom-listview-android/)

And I also recommend you to use recyclerview instead of listview

Comment: The intent are successfully transfer to another activity but the listview now not display the two value in sessionId then listview individual display.

Comment: You are saying within EACH session Id, there are 2 values, right?

Comment: you can achieved that using model class (pojo class)

Comment: YES Mohamed Ashik the sessionId have two value.. but when I viewed the value its individual dispaly

Comment: Then, like @KetanPatel said If you use model class(pojo class) it will be easy to achieve your requirement. I also shared the link for sample app in the answer

Comment: the output: call individual listview 1 and 2 I want the output value in listview its like add items

Comment: can you share some images demonstrating your requirement

Comment: The two value automatic in the card when I inserted and get the two value but I want the value display using the listview or recyclerview for display like items / add item. the image can't add here in the comment but always individual 1 and 2

Comment: Ok I will try the sample app link .. Thank you Mohamed Ashik